# Holding IWebElements as a collection in C#/Selenium when using [FindsBy] attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm trying to set multiple IWebElements to a collection using [FindsBy] attribute included in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects, like following. Suppose I want to hold all "li" elements in instance variable "MyElements".

HTML

```
<ul class="elements">
  <li>e1</li>
  <li>e2</li>
  <li>e3</li>
</ul>
```

C#

```
class TopPage {

  [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "ul.elements li")]
  public IWebElement[] MyElements;

}
```

how can I make this work?

Comment: Well how does it not work at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry guys, solved:

```
class TopPage {
    TopPage(IWebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "ul.elements li")]
    public IList<IWebElement> MyElements;
}
```

Use `IList`, not an `Array`. Thank you!

Comment: Accept the answer to your own question, and next time let us know *how* it doesn't work, thank you!

Comment: I know, but they say "You can accept your own answer in 1 day", I'll do that later.